# clean easily a list of different field for only keep specifics ones

Tags: excel, vba

i tried to recover some field of a long list, more specific the one of name of username.
the data is presented like this :

username           doe

name            john, doe

phonenumber     78974654131

In one cell.

I tried to not use VBA , but with simple formula i can't arrive to the result i want.

=IF(OR(ISNUM(SEARCH(J$1;A1));ISNUM(SEARCH(K$1;A1)));G1=A1;G1=""

where J1="username" and K1="name" and g1 is the cell where is the formula. The trouble is , that when a cell doesn't have name or username , the cell isn't consider as blank and so i can't delete them with control G to only have the lines with those intel.

i have exactly a total of 442134 lines to use this formula on and recover the name and username of all the lines they exist, so delete one by one the blanks cells will take me forever.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your data and clarify which *cell isn't considered as blank*?

Comment: A search for name will find also username. Try `=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("name",A1)),"",A1)`